# What diagnostic tools are available on (specifically Nokia) Windows Phones?

Tags: lumia, diagnostics

Are there any (hidden) diagnostic tools available on Nokia Windows Phones (or Windows Phone in general)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Nokia devices, `##634#` will open the "On-Device Diagnostic Tool" which provides the following tests (on my Lumia 800):

- Accelerometer
- ALS (light sensor)
- APN (override for browser/MMC APNs)
- Audio Loopback
- Bluetooth
- Camera
- Battery Status
- Detailed Battery Info
- DTMF (tone generator)
- Gyroscope
- Hardware Buttons
- Headset Detection
- LCD White (for checking dead pixels)
- Lights (backlight)
- Magnetometer (compass)
- Power Source
- Proximity sensor
- Speaker
- Touch points
- Vibration
- Wireless LAN

Once opened for the first time, the tool will be listed in the applications list as "Diagnostics".

There's also a (Nokia) data field test can be accessed by dialing `##3282#`, but is of dubious use. It [supposedly allows you to enable the data speed limiter on AT&T Lumia 900 devices](http://mobilitydigest.com/lte-too-fast-for-you-try-edge-on-your-lumia-900/), but there's talk that the limiter doesn't actually do anything. In my experience on a Lumia *800*, the data field test never completes so isn't useful at all.

Comment: (Holy bullet list spacing, Batman!)

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that! +1

Comment: It's DTMF, not DTMS, and you mispelled "Accelerometer"

Comment: @Keith - Right you are. You can actually propose edits on SE by clicking 'edit' on a post.

Comment: Yes, but the edit has to be at least 6 characters, and I didn't see more than 2 that needed changing.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Ah, I did not know that :)

Comment: It works for HTC phones, too. (Or at very least it does in my HTC 8S.)

Comment: This opens the [life time counter](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2034/11382) on newer devices like my Lumia 730, [diagnostics doesn't seem to be included in newer devices](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1157/11382). `##3282#` doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WinPhone Info Free App available in the Windows Phone Marketplace at:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/48eddb9a-ca83-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8?wa=wsignin1.0

Its description is:

> WinPhone Info Free displays real-time info about your Windows Phone
>   device in an easy-to-navigate, Metro-styled interface. View detailed
>   info in the category pages, including device, memory, media,
>   miscellaneous, network, region, sensors, and location. Tap the
>   favorite icon next to any item to add it to the favorites list on the
>   main page for quick viewing.

[image: screenshots]

As I write this, it is rated 4.5 stars on 255 ratings.

Answer (score 0):

There is also PhoNetInfo avaialable in the Windows Phone Marketplace:
http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=8c3f5fde-41bc-4b7c-8206-6267f21fb7bc

[image: General tab 1]
[image: General tab 2]
[image: Network tab]
[image: I/F tab]
[image: HAL tab 1]
[image: HAL tab 2]

It retrieves detailed technical phone and network information such as firmware version, device name, battery status, power saving status, network operator, roaming status, wifi/wap interface names, number of CPUs, CPU architecture, CPU features, CPU page size, high performance timer frequency, time since last device reboot, RAM, etc.