# Windows Phone 8 / Lumia 920 diagnostics tool

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, diagnostics

I bought my Lumia 920 yesterday and wanted to have that diagnostics tool I knew from my Lumia 800 / Windows Phone 7.

On my Lumia 800 I just had to enter ##634# into the phone keyboard and then that tool launched and was available in my app list.

Now I tried to get this tool back (e.g. to see the current detailed battery status) but the above code only opened a "Color Variant + Life Time Counter" tool which is quite useless.

Is there a possibility to get this or a similar tool on my Lumia 920?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the xda forums it is mentioned, that there is no diagnostic tool on WP8 :(
[On-Device Diagnostics Tool on WP8 devices](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=8e06b4cc397dae09076ab71f570a5979&p=34131166&postcount=9)

Comment: This appears to be correct, but would be interesting if there was an official link.

Comment: Need some official information