# Detailed battery status?

Tags: lumia, battery

I just switched to Windows phone (Nokia Lumia 930, after using android for ~5 years) and I can't find a lot of things, e.g., incoherent operating system, lag, crashes, substandard apps, lack of apps, carrier bloatware etc. These things I'm happy to live without but I would love to have an android like battery status app/screen that details charging status, discharging status, and battery usage by apps etc.

Below is a screenshot of what the android app/screen looks like

[image]

I've tried the code found in this question ([Windows Phone 8 / Lumia 920 diagnostics tool](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/windows-phone-8-lumia-920-diagnostics-tool)) but it didn't help.

Any help in finding a similar screen/app will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the app by app breakdown in the Battery Saver app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find things in such details but yes we do have some to get details like those. You can try a view to your **All settings->Battery saver.**

Here you will be able to see your *battery status*, then *usage of app*s. You can **allow** and **disallow** them too according to your need.

We windows users are happy with it :)

You as a long time android user will find some lacks for sure. Hope for better future Windows!

Comment: `We windows users`, count me in. _Loving windows phone_ can't be undone ;) Thanks for the suggestion. I never thought battery _saver_ will have statistics in it.

Comment: The battery app suggested by @Andrew looks promising but I'm going for the built-in battery saver app because 1) it is free 2) built by MS 3) provides me with sufficient statistics. Nothing to take away from battery app (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/battery/9wzdncrfjc2z) which could be exactly same as android battery statistics

Comment: @Ejay Ya :) I am sorry :D you are included _too_ now...The second comment of yours is what I think and believe. happy to Help!

Answer (score 5):

I use this app (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/battery/9wzdncrfjc2z) called Battery.

It does everything I have ever wanted (only used Windows smart phone) and I find the statistics really useful.

I then pin it to the home screen and it gives me updated battery statistics.

[image: Windows Phone Battery App]

[image: Windows Phone Battery App Overview]