# How to check if my Nokia Lumia 920 is new?

Tags: settings

I recently bought a Nokia Lumia 920 from eBay. After reading some negative feedback about the seller (yes, after I bought it). I am now worried whether or not the phone I've purchased is an original or a refurbished phone from the Far East.

Is there any way that I can run a check on the phone when it arrives to verify if the phone is new and unused and compatible with Irish networks?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very worried seeing as the phone was very expensive and I don't want to be sold a sub standard version.

Thank you for any help which you may give me.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [life time counter](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Nokia-Lumia/Nokia-Lumia-920-Life-Time-Counter/td-p/1867710) to see how long the phone has been active. You can access it by dialling `##634#`.

Comment: Cool! +1  Is there a list somewhere of all the available dialing codes like ##634#?

Comment: Just for the record - this does not work on the Lumia 520. I get a `COLOR VARIANT + LIFE TIME COUNTER` screen, but all it displays is `BLACK`. Rest of the screen is blank.

Comment: @lkessler There's a list [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2071160).

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: it worked after an update to `extras+info` in the Store. So it actually might not work on new phones, depending on the firmware version.

Comment: What if the sim card isn't inserted to the phone. How can we know that it's a testing one?
Here is my situation, if you read it, please help me : http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/how-to-check-if-nokia-lumia-1520-is-a-testing-one

Comment: hello can i check my purchases date form this type of code

Comment: What exactly these numbers means? I have my Lumia 535 for past two weeks, turned on for past five days and when I type this code, I'm getting `00:02:42` as a result. My phone is active for two hours and 42 minutes? How should I understand this in correlation to real numbers, given above?