# How to check if a device is a testing one

Tags: lumia, settings

I'm going to buy a Nokia Lumia 1520 at a store in my country. Normally, the store will use some phones, charging all the time (without inserting the sim card) for customer testing.

Nokia Lumia 1520 is now quite rare in my country, so how can I check if the one I'm gonna buy is not a testing one? I don't know if they don't insert the sim, whether or not we can check it?

This phone is suitable for my work, my style, I really like it, so please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Test devices are preloaded with dummy data - so when you boot up the phone and there are already account preconfigured you should get suspicious. If the phone just asks you to go through the regular setup process you should be good to go.

raydenrego's tip is also not a bad one. Keep in mind that test / dummy devices rarely come in regular packaging to avoid confusion.

If you do end up with a Showcase device you can always try to Flash a regular ROM onto your phone using the [Lumia Software Recovery tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987).

Answer (score 2):

When your at the store to buy the 1520, make sure the seal in the box that thr phone ships with is intact. If the seal is tampered with ask the retailer for a different unit.

Once you have bought it, if possible open up the box and try to boot the phone right at store. If the phone is damaged or is not booting up, you can ask for a replacement right away.